# Possible to make a route transition inside of a service in Ember?

Tags: ember.js

I'm using ember-cli 1.13.8 and I have a service that handles most of my logic. Right now I have a function that listens to whether certain things are true or false and then can make a route change based upon that. I'd rather not have to call that function from inside every route since I want it to happen on every route.  Its goal is to determine whether the player won and every interaction in the game drives this.

Inside of my game service:

```
init() {
  ... 
  if(true) {
    console.log("you've won!");
    this.transitionTo("congratulations");
  }
},
```

Of course, this fails because `this` isn't a route like Ember expects. I know I can call this method from inside of every route instead but I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Thanks

**Edit**

So far I've tried importing in the App and then trying to extend the Router. This seems like a bad idea though.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use the routing service (which is a private API):

```
routing: Ember.inject.service('-routing'),

init() {
  ... 
  if(true) {
    console.log("you've won!");
    this.get("routing").transitionTo("congratulations");
  }
},
```

Comment: Wow, ok, I'll have to try this. I was unaware of this.

Comment: Does this work in ember 2.x? It's just telling me that routing is undefined in Ember 2.4.0.

Comment: Hi Dwickem, works great and makes the sendAction redundant which for me was kind of a pain. Is -routing an Ember preferred way that you know?

Comment: Note that this (hacked) transitionTo() is slightly different from the normal Route.transitionTo() method. More info here: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/12719#issuecomment-204099140

Answer (score 9):

As of Ember 2.15, there is a public `router` service for exactly this use case. Just add `router: Ember.inject.service(),` to your Ember class and call `this.get('router').transitionTo(...);`, easy!

---

Generally this is a bad idea, but in some cases it's easier than passing through route actions in 100 places (personal experience).

The better way to do this from anywhere is to look the router up on the container:

```
Ember.getOwner(this).lookup('router:main').transitionTo(...);
```

`this` has to be some container allocated Ember object, which includes components, services, and Ember Data models.

Note also that if this will be called a lot, you will want to store the router as a property. You can do this in the `init` hook:

```
init() {
  this._super(...arguments);
  this.set('router', Ember.getOwner(this).lookup('router:main'));
}
...
this.get('router').transitionTo(...);
```

`Ember.getOwner(this)` works in [Ember 2.3+](http://emberjs.com/blog/2016/01/15/ember-2-3-released.html#toc_introducing-owners-and-deprecating-containers), prior to that you can use `this.get('container')` instead.

Comment: Every time lookup may be costly operation, so if possible update your answer with grapho suggestion provided in this [link](https://gist.github.com/grapho/dfa357c63ab3b6c87970d0804a49efd4)

Answer (score 0):

**Ember 1.13:**

Create another service called routing:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Service.extend({
    _router: null,

    init() {
        this._super();

        this.set('_router', this.get('container').lookup('router:main'));
    },

    transitionTo() {
        this.get('_router').transitionTo(...arguments);
    }
});
```

Then you can:

```
routing: Ember.inject.service(),

goSomewhere() {
    this.get('routing').transitionTo('index');
}
```