# Ember 2 - Transition to route through component

Tags: ember.js, ember-router, ember-components

I am trying to make a pagination component for ember 2 app.
Since it is a general purpose pagination component, I wanted to use it on many different routes. Because of that I need to somehow (in my mind) provide a name of my route for pagination links to work.

I can pass in my route name (string) to the component easily:
`{{pagination-component myRoute='myCurrentRouteName'}}`. And 
  inside of component: `{{link-to myRoute (query-params page=1)}}`

It works well for going to pages like: << First, < Previous, Next > , Last >>.

But I also wanted to have a select box with options pointing to all the pages, where if user selects a page, I can transition into that route with queryParams similar to this: `myRoute?page=selectedPage`.
All the tutorials for ember say that transitioning within the component is a no-no.

But how do I do it instead, given that I want my pagination to be generic and I don't want to have action within every single route that deals with pagination and provide same exact transitioning?

So far I found that I can inject the ['-routing'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33334502/possible-to-make-a-route-transition-inside-of-a-service-in-ember/33335230#33335230) into the component, which can work for transitioning within the component, but it also doesn't quiet work for some reason. Plus people say that it is private and unreliable.
I also tried making a Route Mixin with action so I can simply `sendAction` from the component with the `selectedPage`, but I don't know how to get the router (in order to call `router.transitionTo`) within my Mixin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We should use public API for transitioning, that is provided in Route [transitionTo](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_transitionTo) and in  Controller [transitionToRoute](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Controller.html#method_transitionToRoute). this is the recommended approach.

1. As you said, you can make it work in the component using `Ember.getOwner(this).lookup('router:main').transitionTo('myRouteName')` but that's **strongly against** good design.
2. You can define method named `myTransitionToUrl` inside `actions` hash of the `Application` route, and install [ember-route-action-helper](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-route-action-helper) addon to call route action method `myTransitionToUrl` from component.
3. If you don't want to define method in application route, then you can define it in `mixin` and implement it in the required route. that's also will work.
4. **My choice and Recommended approach** would be, Say `pagination-component` has `prev`,`next`,`transtionTo` actions, then I will implement all those actions in [`Mixin`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Mixin.html) and extend it in all route which uses `pagination-component`. and will inform any data changes to route through actions from component. that will ensure [Data Down Actions Up](http://www.samselikoff.com/blog/how-ember-data-affects-data-down-actions-up/) strategy too.
5. If you are just transitioning to a different route, then the Latest possible way is,

If ember version is greater than 2.15, then you can inject [RouterService](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/3.2/classes/RouterService) and and call transitionTo method directly.
If you are using the ember version 2.15 or below, then you can use the [router service polyfill](https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-router-service-polyfill) to use RouterService.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  router: Ember.inject.service(),

  actions: {
    next() {
      this.get('router').transitionTo('other.route');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems I was on the right path. That was the last thing I tried to do (**#4 using Mixin**). But as I mentioned earlier I can extend Mixin in my routes and define actions such as **prev**, **next** in it. The question remains as _How do I reference **router** inside of a Mixin?_ Because it seems that I need to call `router.transitionTo` from within **prev** / **next** actions.

Comment: No. you can just say `this.transitionTo` inside action since `this` refers to route instance

Comment: o, that's right! However I am trying the #4 and I have encountered a problem. Since component is isolated, when I will be calling `this.sendAction` from component, it would not trigger any action. I would have to say `{{pagination-component prev=(route-action 'prev') next=(route-action 'next') ... }}` everywhere where I would want to use that component. Is there a way that these actions be automatically referenced somehow? Since the route Mixin will have the same name for all of these actions (prev,next,etc).

Comment: try `this.get('prev')()` instead of sendAction from `pagination-component`

Comment: hmmm...`this.get('prev')` returns `undefined`. It works if I do `{{pagination-component prev=(route-action 'prev') ... }}`, then `this.get('prev')` becomes defined.

Comment: In fact we need to pass all closure functions argument every time when we use `pagination-component` but then if you don't want to pass then inside component hbs you can directly bind something like `<button {{action (route-action 'prev') }} >Prev</button>

Comment: Yes, and I tried that initially. But as I understand the component is still isolated. When I try this I get an `EmberError`: `Unable to find action prev` . So far I think this is just a limitation of ember components and I would have to say `{{pagination-component prev=(route-action 'prev') next=(route-action 'next') ... }}` for every action?

Comment: Yes you are right. that's the way to go. but then check this [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/604c9dc277fd2b2ddb969cf6f02bd9fa?openFiles=templates.components.my-component.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs) to understand my earlier comment

Comment: I tried the twiddle and it works well! Thanks a lot for posting it! It is just I was trying to use route-action which has a limitation. I was trying to select a certain page with a `select` option, like so:  `<select ... {{action (route-action 'goToPage' myRouteName value="target.value") on='change'}} >`, but route-action cannot work with events ([from what I understand](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-route-action-helper/issues/27)).

Comment: @EmberFreak I am trying from inside mixin and getting this error "this.transitionToRoute is not a function"

Comment: @AnandGupta I suggested to call route function from mixin so that we can re use it for all the required routes.. Now there is better way. that you can use [RouterService transitionTo](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/3.2/classes/RouterService/methods/transitionTo?anchor=transitionTo) method.